# Multiple images in one TextView?

Tags: android, textview, android-image

I would like to know what is the best way to place multiple, small(all of them the same size) images into one TextView? From what I've found, the best way would be to use Html, but how? All of my images are offline ones, so I can copy them for example in the raw folder, if that is the right way. Can anyone point me into the right direction, or show a similar thread, which I did not find? OR, is there any better approach, like don't use TextView, but something else, which can be solved in the layout files, and dynamically filled with images?

Btw, the whole thing I want to do is:

- I have a ListView, filled with items
- each item has different attributes, which I currently print in plaintext(I want to replace theese with images
- atm, I use one separate TextView to display theese attributes
- the number of attributes are random, but at least 1, and typically 3-4(so 1 picture at least, 3-4 typically)

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a layout that can be used for each row of your `ListView` and populate the different elements of that layout based on the data for the row?

For example, if each item has a maximum of 4 attributes, add four ImageViews to the layout, and set their drawables and visibility in `getView` based on the position passed in.

Comment: what I will do is as the following:
Define a LinearLayout with horizontal allignment and centered gravity in the xml. Recognize this at the code, and dynamically add an ImageView to the defined LinearLayout, not exactly what you said, but close enough :)

Comment: You need to be careful building the Views returned by your Adapter dynamically, because of View recycling. In fact, you probably save CPU by having one standard View and calling `setVisibility` versus adding and removing Views from the row's layout every time `getView` is called.

Comment: I wonder now, is this why the pictures get randomly multiplied? I mean sometimes if I should have 3 pictures, I have 3*4, so it gets repeated 3 another times, and sometimes when I should have 3 pics, I got the 3 pics correctly... I was thinking that there is something wrong with the data Im working with, but than the strings should be randomly multiplied too...

Comment: I'd have to see your code to say for sure, but if you are using the `View` that's passed in to `getView` and adding your `ImageView`s to it without removing them, that could certainly happen. When a `View` is recycled, it stays in the same state it was in when the `ListView` row left the screen. If you previously added views to it, they'll still be there when the `View` is passed to `getView` for recycling.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are making smileys in a chat/message application, am I right? ;)

Anyway, the way to go is to use an [`ImageSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html). You can use a `Matcher` to find all text combinations you want to replace, and use a `SpannableStringBuilder` to add `ImageSpan`s to the positions returned by the matcher, this will replace those characters with the image defined by the `ImageSpan`.

Comment: nah, I am improving my train schedule app, where every train has different attributes, like it has bicycle transporting or not, only 2nd class or 1st class too, etcetc :) The answer you mentioned sounds nice enough, I will try this one out as well :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing is for sure : You do not want to put your images inside your textview.

A textview can contain a background but should not be used to contain images.

What you want to do is simply design an item layout that will be used by your adapter to fill the listview.

This item layout will contain a textView that contains only your text and your images. Then in your listAdapter you'll simply show or hide the images you want.

Try to base your layout on a RelativeLayout that will allow you to have a simpler design and even overlap some elements(the images could overlap the textview for example)